# Does TypeScript support class declaration for a namespaced class?

Tags: typescript, marionette

I'm converting JavaScript code to TypeScript, and stuck on the best way to convert my class definitions.

They are extended from Marionette, and the class names are namespaced.  For example, this JavaScript using the 'xyz' namespace:

```
xyz.Marionette.AppRouter = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    instance_name: "AppRouter",

     functionName: function(options) {
     }
});
```

I tried creating this class command equivalent in TypeScript:

```
class xyz.Marionette.AppRouter extends Marionette.AppRouter {
```

but this syntax does not seem supported.

Is is possible declare a class in TypeScript with namespacing?

The answers below (so far) are helpful, but I still don't know how to express this definition, or even if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

> class nameSpace.Marionette.AppRouter extends Marionette.AppRouter {

Declare the namespace and *then* the class:

```
namespace nameSpace.Marionette {
    export class AppRouter {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works great!

I'm still not totally sure about how to define the class though in terms of the extend.  Does it go inside the export class?  Or under the namespace block?  Both are generated TypeScript errors.  thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried mocking this up but had a problem referencing the base AppRouter because the namespaces are the same. It works if I add a qualifier of "base" to the first namespace..

```
namespace base.Marionette {

    export class AppRouter {

        Foo() {
            return "Hello";
        }
    }
}

namespace nameSpace.Marionette {

    export class AppRouter2 extends base.Marionette.AppRouter {

        Bar() {
            var hello = this.Foo();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.  I'm still struggling to understand why I can't just write this in TypeScript:

class nameSpace.Marionette.AppRouter extends Marionette.AppRouter {
    instance_name: string;
});

Am I missing something?